# Get Literal String of Enum Key in JS/ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm defining an Enum as follows:

```
const ExampleEnum = Object.freeze({
    MY_ANSWER: Symbol(0),
    YOUR_ANSWER: Symbol(1)
})
```

I am trying to get 'MY_ANSWER' as an actual string value like so

```
let str = ExampleEnum.MY_ANSWER.toString()
```

but this returns "Symbol(0)".

This should be really simple, but I haven't been able to get anything but the value rather than the key itself.

Comment: what result do you like to get instead?

Comment: updated my answer to give you a more universal function without hardcodig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

A function that works for arbitrary enums would be:

```
function getEnumName(enumDef, value) {
    for(key in enumDef) {
        if(enumDef[key] == value) {
            return key;
        }
    }
}
```

`getEnumName(ExampleEnum, ExampleEnum.MY_ANSWER)` returns `"MY_ANSWER"`

**OLD ANSWER**

You would have to assign the names as strings to the values like this:

```
const ExampleEnum = Object.freeze({
    MY_ANSWER: "MY_ANSWER",
    YOUR_ANSWER: "YOUR_ANSWER"
})
```

If you need your `Symbol` values you could define objects like this:

```
const ExampleEnum = Object.freeze({
    MY_ANSWER: {
        key: "MY_ANSWER",
        value: Symbol(0)
    },
    YOUR_ANSWER: {
        key: "YOUR_ANSWER",
        value: Symbol(0)
    },
})
```

And access the name with `ExampleEnum.MY_ANSWER.key`

Or you could write a helper function if you do not want to alter your enum:

```
function getEnumName(enum) {
    if(enum == ExampleEnum.MY_ANSWER) {
        return "MY_ANSWER";
    }
    if(enum == ExampleEnum.YOUR_ANSWER) {
        return "YOUR_ANSWER";
    }
}
```